# SFrame, graphlab in Python

Tags: python

Can anybody, please, tell me, how I can plot [SFrame](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.html) (or even better [SArray](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SArray.html#graphlab.SArray)) or convert this type to some common type in python.
When I try convert SArray for example to pandas object:

```
pandas.Series(sarray)
```

I got next error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 220, in __init__
    raise_cast_failure=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2566, in _sanitize_array
    subarr = _try_cast(data, False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2517, in _try_cast
    subarr = pa.array(arr, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphlab/data_structures/sarray.py", line 625, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError("Invalid type to use for indexing")
IndexError: Invalid type to use for indexin
```

Consequently I can not save SArray object like csv file or something else...

Once more, what I need is just some kind of plot of SArray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SArray.html#graphlab.SArray) you can use `list(sarray)` to convert back to a standard list. This can then be converted to a pandas series with `pd.Series(new_list)`.

Comment: This is great, sorry I have completely overlooked it in docs.

Comment: In version 0.9 you can do `sa.show()` to get several descriptive plots of your `SArray`.